# Can you elaborate on pBFT for dBFT in relation to PoW and PoS consensus algorithms in layman's terms?

Tags: cryptocurrency, proof-of-work

I've read all other related answers and googled this extensively. My intention and background in asking this question is that I am delving into cryptocurrency and blockchain technology in general. There is considerable misinformation out there regarding Byzantine Fault Tolerance (BFT) and it's relationship to cryptocurrency, that much I can say for certain even with my limited understanding. I will share my own understanding as follows

1. BFT is not comparable to PoW or PoS consensus algorithms as it is merely a quality that a consensus algorithm can have, not a consensus algorithm in and of itself
2. Practical BFT (pBFT) systems could be seen as antithetical to the stated goals of Satoshi Nakamoto in that they are centralized and must be centralized

Again, I've read nearly all the information that I'd be capable of following based on my background and have only a cursory understanding of how it is that pBFT functions, about how it is more final than PoW as a consensus algorithm, as PoW is probabilistic.

**So, with the above in mind, can you please elaborate on pBFT for delegated BFT (dBFT) in relation to PoW and PoS algorithms?**

Thanks to anyone willing to attempt to elucidate what I find to be quite esoteric

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.se. This is clearly off-topic for our site: [Do we want bitcoin/cryptocurrency related questions? A cryptocurrency tag?](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/985/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka actually, the consensus algorithm (which is what is being asked about here I think) of a cryptocurrency _might_ be a cryptographic component, so I wouldn't rule it out a-priori.

Comment: it's certainly not off topic, in any case, in the linked exchange it's mentioned that a given individual is free to answer topics pertaining to cryptocurrency if they so desire. BFT stands for byzantine fault tolerant, which describes a systems tolerance to the byzantine generals problem, which finds it's present usage mostly in tandem with cryptocurrency, but BFT is definitely not a topic exclusively related to cryptocurrency. That being said, being asked what BFT stands for shows that probably it's better to take this to a different forum.

Comment: Further, clearly implies that cryptocurrency related questions are explicitly disallowed, in the form of some type of mandatory notice, header, etc. Nowhere is it clearly stated. Your usage of the word clearly is superfluous and muddles what would have been an otherwise helpful comment. I read your profile in which you requested that people correct your language. Affirming subjective opinion as objective fact is rarely a good thing. Thanks anyways.

Comment: This question is **out of scope** on Crypto SE. You question is not about cryptographic functions used, but about *other* aspects which are rather *design* questions. I suggest to move it to Bitcoin SE.

Comment: These last two comments of the OP must have been pinged to me. I've re-read and re-read our [meta post](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/985/18298) and couldn't see this ` it's mentioned that a given individual is free to answer topics pertaining to cryptocurrency if they so desire` If ever there is a meaning let us know we can modify it. Our current consensus is clear, if related to cryptography (!=cryptocurrency) then [on-topic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: CS has some question on [p|BFT](https://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=practical+Byzantine+Fault+Tolerance) where you might be interested.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this about distributed network's consensus.

Comment: I've looked into our history of questions and it seems we already have some questions on consensus mechanisms in general - as they too try to achieve security goals using protocols and mathematical means in the presence of an adversary - and on [pBFT and BFT](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/46522/23623) specifically. I therefore will not decide to close this question but instead leave it to the community to assemble the five votes if they think it is off-topic.

Comment: @SEJPM isn't it before our consensus? We have programming questions/answers, too, but they are before our consensus, right?

Comment: For what its worth, if you accept questions about MPC, I think you must accept questions about byzantine agreement. MPC is sort of an evolved version of byzantine agreement, inheriting essentially all of the fault tolerance bounds (in both the computational and information theoretic settings, and the synchronous/asynchronous settings, I think). I agree that this particular question may be off-topic, since it's not very technical.

Answer (score 1):

I'd sum it up as follows. There are two classes of byzantine consensus algorithms (also known as BFT state machine replication, or BFT consensus):

- Permissioned consensus. Here, the set of $n$ players is fixed and known to everyone ahead of time. The assumption is that at most $1/3$ (or $1/2$ depending on network assumptions) of the players are malicious. (These have been studied since the late 1970s. PBFT is a specific permissioned consensus protocol published in 1999.)
- Permissionless consensus. Here, the set of players is not known ahead of time, and indeed participants can join and leave the network "at will" over time. The main innovation of Bitcoin/Nakamoto consensus (2008) is to enable some sort of "permissionless consensus".

Permissioned consensus can be used as a building block to build permissionless proof-of-stake consensus. In proof-of-stake, each coin gets one vote in the underlying consensus protocol. Thus, we can run permissioned consensus using each coin as a  player. It is permissionless (in some sense) because we don't need to know who owns the actual coin, and because coins can change hands.

So protocols like Ethereum and Algorand essentially run permissioned protocols using the set of current coins as a set of virtual players. Algorand in particular runs a protocol very similar to PBFT. (Their sortitioning technique applies to permissioned consensus as well.)